# How to restrict ngModel changes effect to other inside ng-template in angular7?

Tags: javascript, angular6, angular7

[image]

This is my code

```js
<ng-template #rowDetailsTmpl let-row="row">
    <div class="row" style="padding: 10px 30px;">    
      <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
        <label> Add Operator </label>
        <input type="string" id={{row.DeskId}}  name={{row.DeskId}}  (ngModelChange)="onChangeOperator($event)" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Search Operator" [(ngModel)]="selectedOperatorEmail">         
      </div>
      
      
      @ViewChild('rowDetailsTmpl', { static: true }) rowDetailsTmpl: TemplateRef<any>;
      
      
      this._dataTableService.rowDetailsTemplate = this.rowDetailsTmpl;
```

In my code input text field using inside ng-template , i set id and name dynamically , but when i change value in textbox it automatically reflect to other input fields. so how to solve this problem in angular7.

Answer (score 0):

in component define the model like array:

```
selectedOperatorEmail: Array<any> = [];
```

in html define ngModel define like this:

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedOperatorEmail[row.DeskId]"
```